# iOS frequent http request standards

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am creating a grocery app and would like a cross-off/uncross function for my list. When I cross off an item, I am setting the crossed-off flag to true in the database (HttpPost). If I decide to uncross the item, I have to set the crossed-off flag to false in the database ( Another HttpPost).

I am wondering how iOS standards work with these frequent calls. Are they stashed locally until a certain point, or are they sending data to and from the server continuously?

Links to this topic would be greatly appreciated. I am using Alamofire for these htttp requests.

Comment: The calls are dispatched right away. They are not stashed by either iOS or the Alamofire library.

Comment: @H4K follow up question — do i retrieve a new list of the crossed/uncrossed list each time the list is modified or do i do that locally?

Comment: It totally depends upon your implementation. How I would have implemented such a functionality is to fetch the entire list when user lands on the listing screen for the first time. Later upon cross/uncross of a single item I would make a post request updating only the single item.